# Can't change font color onClick inside PHP & Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I just want to change font color in href with function. But i seems troubling with quot.

This is my code :

```
<script>
    <?php foreach($locations AS $loc) { //you could replace this with your while loop query ?>
            var x = '<?php echo $loc['tgl'];?>';
                addMarker(<?php echo $loc["lat"]; ?>, <?php echo $loc["ltd"]; ?> ,'<?php echo $loc["order"]; ?>',x );
                document.getElementById('left').innerHTML += "<?php echo "<li><a href='#' id='".$loc['order']."' onClick='changeColor('".$loc['order']."');return false;'>".$loc["order"]."</a></li>";?>";
            <?php } ?>
</script>
```

And this is the function :

```
<script>
    function changeColor(id)
    {
      document.getElementById(id).style.color = "#1FFF48"; // forecolor
    }
</script>
```

I have tried just only inside in HTML and it succeed. But inside javascript im pretty confused. Any help ?

Comment: I'll try this code, it's working perfectly. Check id generated properly or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this, it will work

```
<?php $order="onClick=changeColor('".$loc['order']."');return false;";  ?>
    document.getElementById('left').innerHTML += "<?php echo "<li><a href='#' id='".$loc['order']."' $order >".$loc["order"]."</a></li>";?>";
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. It is the result : <li><a href='#' id='000000004' onClick='changeColor(\'000000004\');return false;'>000000004</a></li>

Comment: Great ! Thank you so much !

Comment: Welcome... @LeonardFebrianto

Answer (score 0):

After generating your code its look like

```
<li><a href='#' id='order1' onClick='changeColor("order1");return false;'>Order1</a></li>
<li><a href='#' id='order2' onClick='changeColor("order2");return false;'>Order2</a></li>
```

check your id also

```
function changeColor(id)
  {
    alert(id);
    document.getElementById(id).style.color = "#1FFF48"; // forecolor
  }
```

Comment: the matter is, that function didn't even called before.

Answer (score 0):

Its the same answer as kim but try using **eventlistener** inside script tag. This works!!

HTML

```
<li><a href='#' id='order1'>Order1</a></li>
<li><a href='#' id='order2'>Order2</a></li>
```

Script

```
<script>
document.getElementById("order1").addEventListener("click",changeColor);
document.getElementById("order2").addEventListener("click",changeColor);

 function changeColor() {
    this.style.color = "#cecece";
    return false;
 }
</script>
```